# How to only Auto-Refresh a div if the content has changed?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am hoping this is possible.

What I am doing is using the Facebook PHP SDK and the Social Graph API to retrieve posts from a page and refreshing it every x millseconds but this is a bit of waste of resources if the content is exactly the same so I was wanting to only do the refresh is the content has changed.

```
<div id="bottom-bar">
    <?php require("graph.php"); ?>
</div>

<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $('#bottom-bar').fadeOut("slow").load('graph.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 30000); // refresh every 30000 milliseconds
</script>
```

So, `graph.php` has the massive array that is returned by the page and I am taking out the data I want etc but is there a way to only do it if it's different than before?

Thanks for all your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help, managed to get it with the following code so if anyone runs into this situation then hopefully it's of some use to you:

```
<script>
var cacheData;
var data = $('#bottom-bar').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'graph.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                cacheData = data;
                $('#bottom-bar').fadeOut("slow").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 30000); // check every 30000 milliseconds
</script>
```

Comment: That is a purely cosmetic change - you are still transmitting the whole thing each time, just omitting the display part.

Comment: @Piskvor - yes I know but I don't see a way to do this a more elegant and efficient way - do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @martincarlin87 have you considered accepting Piskvor's answer, or giving a reason as to why his answer won't work? For the sake of someone else who might be looking at this?

Comment: @Brian Deragon - I had already submitted my own answer and accepted before Piskvor posted his. In my answer the requests will still be made but the element shouldn't fade  in and out. To do what Piskvor suggested is a bit more complicated but you can let me know if you manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need cooperation from the server-side script, but it is possible to eliminate most of the transfers using conditional requests. HTTP has a feature which allows the server to only send a response if it hasn't changed.

For the PHP part, you can use e.g. [this module](http://alexandre.alapetite.fr/doc-alex/php-http-304/index.en.html#download) (or reimplement the conditional logic yourself).

For the AJAX part, if you use GET (as POST is non-cacheable), the response will be cached and data will only be transferred if it has changed, else it will come from the local browser cache.

There are some caveats, especially if your pages are served with an Expires header ([see here](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/)).

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, if I have time I will try and get it working but for just now I will stick with the dirty method as I am running quite tight for time at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar by creating a JSON string and storing it in a hidden text field, then use setInterval and AJAX to compare the strings. If the strings dont match call another function to reload.

Comment: this sounds like what I would like to do, do you have the code handy by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery - why not just load the contents of graph.php asynchronsly anyway?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/graph.php',
    type: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#bottom-bar').html(data).fadeIn("slow");     
    }
})
```

Comment: do you mean to do it this way rather than my initial `require('graph.php')` ? Just wondering if there are any benefits to changing it or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
var cacheData;
var data = $('#bottom-bar').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                cacheData = data;
                $('#bottom-bar').html(data);
            }         
        }
    })
}, 300); // check every 30000 milliseconds
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="bottom-bar">test
</div>

            <div id="test">
                Testing
            </div>
            <div id="staticBlock">
                This is a static block
            </div>
</body>
</html>


 <?php
echo "Hello World <br />";
$counter = rand();
echo $counter;
?>

<div class="author-avatar"> <img data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: inline;" alt="" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a9c17d250b9b97a7baf76ac13d817a08?s=64&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a9c17d250b9b97a7baf76ac13d817a08?s=128&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-64 photo" width="64" height="64"><noscript><img
alt='' src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a9c17d250b9b97a7baf76ac13d817a08?s=64&#038;d=mm&#038;r=g" srcset='http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/a9c17d250b9b97a7baf76ac13d817a08?s=128&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /></noscript></div>
```